# Why do i get this exception?

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, pop3, gmail-pop

This method gives the number of emails in the inbox.But it gives me this exception :

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: Connect failed;
 nested exception is:
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connecterror
```

-

```
 Session session = Session.getInstance(new Properties());
    try {
        Store store  = session.getStore("pop3");
        store.connect("pop.gmail.com" , "username" , "password");
        Folder fldr = store.getFolder("INBOX");
        fldr.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);
        int count = fldr.getMessageCount();
        System.out.println(count);
    } catch(Exception exc) {
        System.out.println(exc + "error");
    }
```

Comment: gmail's pop3 service is over tls/ssl (port 995) not the standard 110 plain tcp you might wanna check that

Comment: @ ratchet freak so what should i add in my code ?

Comment: check http://www.java-tips.org/other-api-tips/javamail/connecting-gmail-using-pop3-connection-with-ssl-2.html it connects with gmail in particular it sets some settings and uses `URLName` to specify it

Comment: Does it happen only in production or even on a machine without a firewall?

Comment: @grassPro you solve it by using Suhail Gupta;s answer ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this :

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("mail.pop3.host" , "pop.gmail.com");
props.put("mail.pop3.user" , "username");
// Start SSL connection
props.put("mail.pop3.socketFactory" , 995 );
props.put("mail.pop3.socketFactory.class" , "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory" );
props.put("mail.pop3.port" , 995);

Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props , new Authenticator() {
    @Override
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication( "username" , "password");
            }
});
try {
    Store store  = session.getStore("pop3");
    store.connect("pop.gmail.com" , "username" , "password");
    Folder fldr = store.getFolder("INBOX");
    fldr.open(Folder.HOLDS_MESSAGES);
    int count = fldr.getMessageCount();
    System.out.println(count);
} catch(Exception exc) {
    System.out.println(exc + " error");
}
```

Also visit [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6805351/counting-the-number-of-emails-in-the-gmail-inbox)

Comment: Hi i am getting javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: EOF on socket

Comment: @RakshitSoni Suggests that you are using incorrect username and password. It could fail if you use double authentication on google. You will have to register your application with google(In case you use double authentication)

Answer (score 3):

Probably because the server refuses to connect.

Try connecting from "telnet".  Once you can connect at all, then you should be able to connect from your Java program.

Here are some troubleshooting tips:

- http://www.anta.net/misc/telnet-troubleshooting/pop.shtml
- https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21097014
- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/885685

Comment: I could be wrong, but I don't believe Gmail would accept a telnet connection

Comment: @gravity they do; the support pages tell you to do a telnet test to check for a blocked 995 tcp port

Answer (score 1):

Try changing

```
store.connect("pop.gmail.com" , "username" , "password");
```

to

```
store.connect("pop.gmail.com" , 995, "username" , "password");
```

Disclaimer: I have not tested this.

Gmail requires a secure SSL connection, and maybe javax.mail.Service isn't providing that.  I think the more likely explanation, though, is that you're simply not connecting to the right port, so I've explicitly specified the correct port number for Gmail's POP3 service.

Comment: This is the exception reported then : `javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: EOF on socketerror`

Answer (score 1):

Try following a "how to use gmail as an smtp server" [tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/java/javamail-api-sending-email-via-gmail-smtp-example/). Google also has a [configuration page](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=13287) with all the settings you'll need.